# How to skip a character when using Scanner

Tags: java, text, java.util.scanner

I want to read words from a text file which looks like:

```
"A","ABILITY","ABLE","ABOUT","ABOVE","ABSENCE","ABSOLUTELY","ACADEMIC","ACCEPT","ACCESS","ACCIDENT","ACCOMPANY", ...
```

I read the words using `split("\",\"")` so I have them in a matrix. Unfortunately I cannot skip reading the first quotation mark, which starts my .txt file, so as a result in my console I have:

```
"A
ABILITY
ABLE
ABOUT
ABOVE
```

Do you know how can I skip the first quotation mark? I was trying both

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\"");
```

and `parts[0].replace("\"", "");`, but it doesn't work.

```
package list_1;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class exercise {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
      File file = new File("slowa.txt");
      Scanner in = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\"");     //delimiter doesn't work!

      String sentence = in.nextLine();
      String[] parts = sentence.split("\",\"");
      parts[0].replace("\"", "");                 //it doesn't work!

      for (int i=0; i<10 ; i++){
          System.out.println(parts[i]);
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings are immutable which means that you can't change their state. Because of that `replace` doesn't change string on which it was invoked, but creates new one with replaced data which you need to store somewhere (probably in reference which stored original string). So instead of

```
parts[0].replace("\"", "");
```

you need to use

```
parts[0] = parts[0].replace("\"", "");
```

---

Anyway setting delimiter and using `nextLine` doesn't make much sense because this method is looking for line separators (like `\n` `\r` `\r\n`), not your delimiters. If you want to make scanner use delimiter use its `next()` method.

You can also use different delimiter which will represent `"` or `","`. You can create one with following regex `"(,")?`.

So your code could look like

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\"(,\")?");
while(in.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(in.next());
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use this regular expression. It works for me:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\"(,\")?"); 
while(in.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(in.next());
}
```

Comment: The code is exactly the same as in the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30020423/1402846).